# trying to return a view from database but getting -"Undefined variable error - Laravel 5.2"

Tags: laravel

Controller,Route and view code is below.
Getting error

trying to return a view from database but getting -"Undefined variable error - Laravel 5.2"

**Football.blade.php**

```
@if (isset($football_datas)) 
    @foreach($football_datas as $football_data)    
        {{$football_data->day}}      
        </h3>

        <div style="height:20px;">
            <p class="time-identity" > 14:00</p> 
            <a href="{{Route('stream')}}"    > 
                <p class="match-identity">{{$football_data->country}} vs {{$football_data->country}}</p>
                <p  class="live-video-identity"> video </P>
            </a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**football_dataController.php**

```
class football_datacontroller extends controller
{      
    public function index(){
        $football_datas= DB::table('football_datas')->select('id','country','day')->get();


        return view('football',['football_datas'=>$football_datas]);
    }
}
```

**routes**

```
Route::post('football', 'football_dataController@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this on your Controller.

```
    return view('football',compact('football_datas'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
return view('football',['football_datas'=>$football_datas]);
```

Try

```
return View::make('football')->with('football_datas', $football_datas);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way for variables, so you wont need to do all them custon changes:

```
class football_datacontroller extends controller
{      
    public function index(){
        $football_datas= DB::table('football_datas')->select('id','country','day')->get();

        $vars['football_datas'] = $football_datas;
        return view('football', $vars);
    }
}
```

Then, you can add several "$vars['blabla]' = $blabla" on top of eachother, and all variables will be available in the view with just the {{$football_datas}} or {{$blabla}} in the examples provided.

Example here under on how to have several:

```
class football_datacontroller extends controller
{      
    public function index(){
        $football_datas= DB::table('football_datas')->select('id','country','day')->get();

        $vars['blabla'] = $blabla;
        $vars['football_datas'] = $football_datas;
        return view('football', $vars);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also always datadump to be sure what variables you've got, and even use lazy loading.

Comment: still getting " Undefined variable: football_datas " error

Comment: Should be impossible. Could you in any way make us view your files on an FTP or such? Routing correct?